# RxJava : Network & cache emit partial results

Tags: android, android-sqlite, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a simple case to resolve, but I haven't found how to implement it with RxJava yet. On one side I have Retrofit (network) and on the other side my SQLite database (cache).

What I would like to achieve is :

- If there is nothing in the cache: call the API
- If there is something in the cache:

  - if the dataset is up-to-date: emit only the results from the db
  - if the dataset is outdated: emit the outdated results and then call the API (and emit the results)

Do you have any idea how to implement this behavior with Rxjava (version 1)?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

There's already a lot of articles on that case. To name a few:

- [Loading data from multiple sources with RxJava - Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/)
- [Pseudo caching : retrieve data first from a cache, then a network
  call (using concat, concatEager, merge or publish) - Kaushik
  Gopal](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/README.md#9-pseudo-caching--retrieve-data-first-from-a-cache-then-a-network-call-using-concat-concateager-merge-or-publish)
- [Chaining multiple sources with RxJava - Miguel Juárez](https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/chaining-multiple-sources-with-rxjava-20eb6850e5d9#.8cd0x9xcx)

Comment: I known, but the particularity here is to emit partial results in the last case

Comment: @g123k use any kind of reactive database: StorIO, SQLBrite(recommend!), Realm(not a fan)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
    Observable<Foo> cache = getCacheFoo();
    Observable<Foo> network = getNetworkFoo();

    Observable<Foo> foos = cache.flatMap(cachedFoo -> {
        if (cachedFoo == null) {
            // if the cache returns nothing, return the network observable
            return network;
        } else if (cachedFoo.isStale()) {
            // if the cache is stale, return the data, but follow up with the network
            return Observable.just(cachedFoo).concatWith(network);
        } else {
            // otherwise the data is fresh, simply return it
            return Observable.just(cachedFoo);
        }
    });
```